# Webpack 4 devtool option does not work with webpack-dev-server

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, source-maps

Before I decided to post this issue, I did quite a few things as a background check.
So, my problem is:

**- I use webpack v4.6.0 and webpack-dev-server v3.1.3
- they work fine together, but now I am trying to set up source maps for my application, it seems that [devtool option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) does not work.**

At least for me, I have tried and tested every option from the list:

- [Webpack 4 - Sourcemaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986641/webpack-4-sourcemaps) :
  this issue suggests that `devtool: 'source-map'` should work out of the box, but this is not the case for me
- [how to make webpack sourcemap to original files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185748/how-to-make-webpack-sourcemap-to-original-files) : adding  `devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>'file://' + path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/')` to my output config did not help much, instead of client.js it shows index.js for me though[image][image]
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6400 : this one is not an accurate description of my issue, by trying the methods here did not seem to help me either
- I tried to use `webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin`but it doesn't work with my setup  either, even when I delete devtools or set them to false
- I do not use UglifyJS plugin here
- I know that webpack-dev-server is in maintenance now, so I tried webpack-serve, but it seems like source maps do not work with it either
- I have tried source-map-support package as well, but no luck either, have a similar situation as [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3165): [image]

Do you know if that issue is going to be fixed by some PR or have you tried to solve it yourself? Any tips or help is appreciated!

**I would like to get output as described here, [in blogpost](http://erikaybar.name/webpack-source-maps-in-chrome/) with direct links to my files and the original files code.**

My webpack.js

```js
// webpack v4.6.0
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const stylish = require('eslint/lib/formatters/stylish');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: { main: './src/index.js' },
  output: {
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      'file://' + path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].[hash].js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        options: {
          formatter: stylish
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
    //   filename: '[file].map',
    //   moduleFilenameTemplate: undefined,
    //   fallbackModuleFilenameTemplate: undefined,
    //   append: null,
    //   module: true,
    //   columns: true,
    //   lineToLine: false,
    //   noSources: false,
    //   namespace: ''
    // }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin('dist', {}),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: false,
      hash: true,
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new WebpackMd5Hash(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
};
```

my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "post",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9001 -c .storybook",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^3.4.3",
    "@storybook/react": "v4.0.0-alpha.4",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "prettier": "^1.12.1",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "webpack": "v4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "v3.1.3",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.6",
    "webpack-serve": "^0.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.5"
  }
}
```

my output in console is: [image]

**Edit:**

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49477274/webpack-4-2-how-can-i-obtain-the-original-source-file-name-and-line-line-numbe), but nobody seems to be answering.
**The error was made on purpose!**
This does not just apply to linting errors but to every error my my app.
***[Here is a link to my GITHUB repo: https://github.com/marharyta/webpack-fast-development](https://github.com/marharyta/webpack-fast-development)***

***UPDATE 01.05.2018***

I have created another repo with cleaner setup: https://github.com/marharyta/webpack-4.6.0-test
And detailed explanation of how I got there here: https://medium.com/p/79fb676417f4/edit
Some suggestions were given by the webpack contributors but that still did not work for me: https://github.com/marharyta/webpack-4.6.0-test/issues/1

***UPDATE 02.05.2018***

After a long investigation, I posted my answer below. The problem was ESLint and probably some mode markings since I had to do it the CLI way.
I also an issue in ESLint loader here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-loader/issues/227
I also created a post with a more detailed description here: https://medium.com/@riittagirl/how-to-solve-webpack-problems-the-practical-case-79fb676417f4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, after a long tried and error, I finally got help from one of webpack mainteiners.
The main issue was eslint. If you load it as a loader, it creates unexpected behaviour. 
By deleting the eslint from webpack loaders for js you can fix that.

The webpack setup before:

```js
// webpack v4
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const baseConfig = {
  entry: { main: './src/index.js' },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].[hash].js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true,
    open: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        **use: [
          { loader: 'babel-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            options: { formatter: require('eslint/lib/formatters/stylish') }
          }**
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin('dist'),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: false,
      hash: true,
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new WebpackMd5Hash()
  ]
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  baseConfig.devtool = 'inline-source-map';
}

module.exports = baseConfig
```

the webpack that works after:

```js
// webpack v4
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  entry: { main: './src/index.js' },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].[hash].js'
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true,
    open: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        **use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' }]**
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin('dist'),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: false,
      hash: true,
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new WebpackMd5Hash()
  ]
};
```

my packeje.json looks like:

```js
{
  "name": "post",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode=production",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --mode=development --hot"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "prettier": "^1.12.1",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3"
  }
}
```

See also the suggestions from the issue that was created on my branch:
https://github.com/marharyta/webpack-4.6.0-test

Comment: Thank you so much! My bundle size went from 8 mb parsed to 1.6 mb parsed after removing ESlint and setting devtool: null. Prior to this setting devtool: null would produce a smaller production bundle but one that didn't work :). Removing eslint was the missing step. I never would have figured this out without your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In webpack4, you need to set the mode in your webpack config. Please add

```
mode: "development"
```

To your webpack config.

You can remove NamedModulesPlugin because it is already used in dev mode.

The option `source-map` is meant for production builds.
For your dev build, i would remove the devtool prop, because then, webpack uses `eval` as default.
If it shouldn't work then try:

```
devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'
```

That is what I use. Most minimal config.

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const stylish = require('eslint/lib/formatters/stylish');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: { main: './src/index.js' },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[hash].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    open: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'babel-loader' },
          { loader: 'eslint-loader', options: { formatter: stylish } }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin('dist'),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Comment: Setting mode doesnt help unfortunately

Comment: Have you also removed this devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate?

Comment: Posted my minimal config.

Comment: By pasting your suggestions into my config it doesn't get fixed unfortunately, Maybe you can give me more info on why having NamedModulesPlugin might be a problem?

Comment: No NamedModulesPlugin is not a problem. I just wanted to tell you, that it is not needed anymore.

Comment: Also your linter throws errors at you. You should fix them first.

Comment: I made some errors on purpose to see how the browser handles them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170109/discussion-between-daniel-and-margarita).